# CSS3 Flexbox Webkit, column flow and horizontal scrolling

Tags: css, webkit, flexbox

I have the following list:

```
<ul class="contacts">
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>def</li>
    <li>ghi</li>
    <li>jkl</li>
    <li>mno</li>
    <li>pqr</li>
    <li>stu</li>
    <li>vwx</li>
    <li>yz0</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>456</li>
    <li>789</li>
</ul>
```

With styles

```
ul { display: -webkit-flex; width: 800px; height: 600px; overflow-x: scroll; -webkit-flex-direction: column; }
ul li { width: 400px; height: 200px; }
```

Assuming the parent container is a fixed size of 800px x 600px, I would like the content to flow vertically, then horizontally so that the final layout would be:

```
abc  jkl  stu  123
def  mno  vwx  456
ghi  pqr  yz0  789
```

How do I achieve this with (webkit) flexbox? I can't seem to get the list items to flow once the third list item reaches the bottom of the parent container. Please note that I would like horizontal scrolling as the number of items in the list is indeterminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer - I needed to use the -webkit-flex-flow property.

```
ul { display: -webkit-flex; width: 800px; height: 600px; overflow-x: scroll; -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap; }
ul li { width: 400px; height: 200px; }
```